# Extract information before several special characters in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have a problem with an excel file.

I am trying to extract information from a column. This information appears randomly, before a ".", "-" or ":". So an example would be:

| CELL | EXPECTED RESULT |
| --- | --- |
| hi.this is: | hi |
| maybe I- this works | maybe I |
| Who is: what. like- | Who is |

I am using the formula:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND("-",A1,1)-1)
```

Using this one, I get the information I need, but I am not able to add the other characters (".", ":",...) to the formula. Also I have the problem that in a same cell, I can have several of this characters, and I only want the information before the FIRST character (of all posible kinds) that appears in the cell.

I dont know if somebody can help me here.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1:A3,{".","-",":"})
```

---

If you don't yet have acces to `TEXTBEFORE()` then try:

```
=LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND({".","-",":"},A1&".-:"))-1)
```

I suppose this is an array-entered formula in versions prior to ms365.